# Java: How to provide <Class<List<CustomObject>>> as an argument for a function that defines that argument as type: Class<T>?

Tags: java, generics, jackson

Superclass:

```
protected Container(
            Class<TSourceT> sourceClass,
            Class<TResultT> resultClass) {
        this(sourceClass, resultClass);
    }
```

Child class:

```
public class ServicesContainer
        extends Container<List<Service>, HashMap> {
   super( *WHAT TO PUT HERE*, HashMap.class)
}
```

The more I research this issue the more I find it impossible. Let me know if you can help!!!!!!

Comment: It's _not_ really possible, and the best you'll be able to do is casting `List.class`.